# Get my domain in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to get my domain name: `http://localhost:3000` in dev, or `mydomain.com` in production.

I don't want to use `request.host`, because my request may come from a different website. How should I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'd use `request.domain`. Take a look at the [ActionController Overview - Request & Response Objects](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-and-response-objects) section for more info.

For clarification, `request.domain` will return the hostname of the server used for the request, not the hostname of the visitor. Unless you are hosting your application using multiple domains you should get the value you are expecting (e.g. `mydomain.com`)

Comment: Hi Dan, just want to clafity: if a customer clicks a link on facebook.com and go to MyDomain.com, what request.domain will show?

Comment: If the user clicks a link on facebook.com that points to `http://mydomain.com/some/path` the value of `request.domain` will be `mydomain.com`.

Comment: @DanReedy How to get the hostname of the visitor(facebook.com)?

Comment: @PeterPrabu facebook.com would not be the hostname of the client, but the referrer. Feel free to look for a question on this specific issue, there should be a bunch on SO :)

Comment: `request.domain` returns nil when you are in dev (when the host is 0.0.0.0:3000)

Answer (score 27):

I know this is an old question but it ranks highly in search. In case anyone stumbles across this looking to retrieve the domain *with* the protocol, you can use:

```
request.base_url
#=> http://localhost:3000 # dev
#=> https://example.com # prod
```

Hope that's handy for someone.